# How to alternate child placement to the left and right in a vertical stack?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Is it possible to arrange alternate children separately in a vertical layout group?

I want to arrange the child elements so that one is aligned to the left, the next one is aligned to the right, and so on, alternating like this:

[image: Alternating arrangement]

How can I achieve this layout?

Comment: Why not use 2 vertical groups and add enough spacing between elements to get that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my solution is to create a parent object and set these elements as children. Then, I anchor one child element to the right and the other to the left. This fixed my problem, but I'm not sure if it's best practice.

Comment: If it works for you game, it is good enough. Easy solutions and especially solutions that you understand what/ why/ how they are working are better than a perfected solution where you understand nothing